# Using aliases when importing from other modules in elm

Tags: import, elm

I wonder if there is a way to import something from a module and rename it straight away.

Here’s what I can do in a JavaScript file assuming that `"my-module"` exports `myFunction` and `somethingElse`:

```
import { myFunction as myRenamedFunction, somethingElse } from "my-module";
```

Here’s what I’m trying to like to do in Elm, but this produces a syntax error:

```
import MyModule exposing (myFunction as myRenamedFunction, somethingElse)
```

Answer (score 6):

No, there is no syntax for renaming imports as of Elm 0.18. The closest you can get is to declare a function like this:

```elm
import MyModule exposing (somethingElse)

myRenamedFunction = MyModule.myFunction
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer Chad! Do you think if there is a specific design decision behind this? If not, perhaps I could open an issue in the elm compiler repo and ask to support `as`.

Comment: The Elm language designers tend to be conservative in terms of adding syntax. The past few releases have stripped away otherwise useful syntax that they see as a barrier towards newcomers. This feels like one of those things that they would feel is superfluous, so I doubt they would give it much consideration, but it never hurts to try!

Comment: I actually found a similar feature request in issues: https://github.com/elm-lang/elm-compiler/issues/1450. Added a comment to it. Thanks again for your answer!

Comment: Elm's official guide "recommend[s] using `exposing` pretty rarely. Ideally on zero or one of your imports." So the absance of this is rather a design choice to keep things simple and explicit.

https://guide.elm-lang.org/webapps/modules.html